# Is there any way to muffle the engine braking noise from trucks?

Tags: engine, diesel, muffler

We have all heard the loud and annoying rap-rap-rap as truckers apply compression braking for their engines, especially going down hill.  Is there a something they can install to muffle this?

Comment: What about the boy-racer loud exhausts can we change them? The times I have heard this noise is small compared to the distance I have travelled - will it be worth the expense?

Comment: Yes. It's called a retarder or transmission brake. It replaces the compression brake, and operates silently.

Comment: Cost comparison? Is that why truck manufacturer's fit them?